# How to accept user inpus from any console in shell script?

Tags: shell, daemon

I have this snippet of code

**test.sh =>**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "i am running......."
while true  
        do
        echo "you typed  -----  $1" 
done
```

I just want something like where ever i type `test hello`, it should print `you typed  -----  hello`.

example:
**Console-1**

```
vagrant@dummy:~$ sh test.sh
i am running.......
```

**Console-2**

```
vagrant@dummy:~$ test hello
you typed  -----  hello
```

like it should run like daemon process and i should call it from anywhere. any help?

Answer (score 1):

you could try

```
#!/bin/bash

# read will return true as long as it reads the "delimiter" 
while read -p "Please enter something: "
do
    if [[ $REPLY == "stop" ]]
    then
        # break exits the "while" loop
        break
    else
        printf "%s\n" "you entered $REPLY"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK for what you want as the output.

To be able to run it from anywhere -

- Rename your script to **test** from **test.sh**
- Place your script at a location which is included in your $PATH variable.

For e.g.,

```
$ echo $PATH
/bin:/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin
```

Either you can place the script in one of the above directories, or you can set PATH to include more locations and when you export PATH in your .profile or .bash_profile, it will be exported automatically each time you login.

Add this in your ~/.profile -

```
export PATH=$PATH:/dir/to/script
```

Place the script in /dir/to/script. Now every time you login, PATH will be like -

```
$ echo $PATH
/bin:/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/script/to/dir
```

Now, you can run the script from anywhere -

```
$ test hello
```